# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exact' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I've built a react app and it works fine using `npm start`, so now I am trying to deploy it to a server.

I am trying to use Nginx to deploy the app, but after building it I suddenly get an error which doesn't happen when using `npm start`.

So I configured Nginx, built the app using `npm run build`, but now when I visit the index through my servers IP I get the following

```
error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exact' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (react-router-dom.js:288)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Module.951 (Home.js:14)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.434 (profile.svg:1)
    at f ((index):1)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Array.e [as push] ((index):1)
    at main.22a79b93.chunk.js:1
```

It appears to be something with my react router, which is as follows:

```
import {Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
      <CookieConsent buttonText="Accept">

      </CookieConsent>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/Account" component={Account}/>
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout}/>
      </Switch>

      <Route
        path="/dashboard"
        render={({ match: { url } }) => (
          <Authenticator>
                  <Dashboard>
                    <Switch>
                      <Route path={`${url}/Account`} component={Account} exact />
                      <Route path={`${url}/Profile`} component={Profile} exact />
                      <Route path={`${url}/`} component={Account} exact />
                      <Route component={Page404Dashboard} />
                    </Switch>
                  </Dashboard>
        </Authenticator>
        )}/>

  </Router>
```

But I cannot find anything here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try building it with source maps? Maybe run built version locally, with for example `http-server` or `serve` from npm. Do you get an error only on remote server?

Comment: @Tymek I just built and deployed it using serve locally, it raises the same issues.

Comment: maybe add `/dashboard` `Route` inside the `Switch`? Or change `${url}` to `/dashboard/`. Also, how are you importing `Router` ? Please show that part of the code

Comment: @Vencovsky I tried both to no avail, I've added the import to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by updating react-router-dom and react-router from version 5.0.0 to 5.0.1.